# Emberjs view binding for Google maps markers

Tags: javascript, ember.js, coffeescript

I have a /companies route set up which uses my `Company` model to retrieve companies.  I also have a Map view which I'm trying to display my companies on. I can't seem to find a way to get the list of companies inside of the view.

With the code below, the map renders as expected and the company names are all printed as paragraphs.

```
window.App = Ember.Application.create()

App.Router.map ->
  @resource 'companies'

App.CompaniesRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: ->
    App.Company.find()

App.Map = Ember.View.extend
  tagName: 'div'

  didInsertElement: ->
    opts =
      zoom: 12
      center: new google.maps.LatLng 37.762030, -122.441940
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP

    e = @get 'element'
    m = new google.maps.Map e, opts
```

My template looks like this:

```
{{#each model}}
  <p>{{name}}</p>
{{/each}}

{{view App.Map}}
```

The company names all get displayed, I just can't find any way to get a hold of the model/content from within the View.

So far I've tried `@get 'model'` from within `didInsertElement`. I've tried creating a `markersBinding` property on the View with a range of inputs like 'controller.content' and 'controller.model' and 'route.model' - all to no avail.  I also tried adding another method on the view which observes each of the bindings I attempted.

I feel like I must be missing something.  How can I subscribe/observe the content/model in my View?

Thanks.

Comment: maybe for your use case you need to hook into the `render` method?

Comment: Something like {{view App.Map markersBinding="content"}} should work actually. What did not work with this approach?

Comment: Aha. I had been writing the markersBinding within the view itself, not the template. I tried the above in the template and it works. Thanks very much!

Comment: Finbarr, I'm running into the same issue and I think I'm still missing something - would it be possible for you to post the updated code that worked for you? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @iqnivek I actually ended up abandoning Ember and switching to another framework. Good luck trying to figure it out.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is unanswered for several years, and asks about an extremely old version. It is unlikely to be answered in its current form. If you still need an answer for this under a newer version, please edit the question so that it may be reopened.