# EmberJS View programmatically using a not loaded model

Tags: google-maps-api-3, ember.js, ember-data

I have a model:

```
App.Checkin = DS.Model.extend({
  latitude: DS.attr('string'),
  longitude: DS.attr('string'),
  time: DS.attr('number')
});
```

And a route that loads the collection of checkin models (making a request with ember-data) by

```
model: function() {      
  return this.store.find('checkin');
}
```

And then in the template for the route I have

```
{{view App.MapView}}
```

And I need to access the model programmatically so that I can iterate over each item in the model to add a pin to the map.

Inside my view I have

```
didInsertElement: function() {
   var data = this.get("context.content");
}
```

and data is

> Class {type: function, store: Class, isLoaded: true, isUpdating: true, toString: function…}

In the network window, the request to the server hasn't completed by that point, so it obviously wouldn't have data to provide. (Even if it did, I don't know how to query an object like that, none of the expected methods worked (get/forEach))

I believe that I need to observe the model being changed, and have tried

```
updatePins: function() {
  debugger;
}.observes('context.content')
```

inside of the view. I have tried binding to all sorts of things, but reRender has never been called. I've tried the recommendations on [Emberjs view binding for Google maps markers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16600587/emberjs-view-binding-for-google-maps-markers)
by trying to bind to controller.content, context, App.Checkin, etc.

How do I go about getting the data from the model once it has loaded...inside of the view?

Answer (score 1):

Until the model does not resolve what you get is a promise for that model, obviously the promise does not contain the data just yet but when the request comes back from the server. You could check in your template if the model has data, by observing the `model.length` property for example using an `if` helper, the `if` helper block will re-evaluate when the `length` property changes this beeing when it has received data.

For example, you could try something like this:

```
...
{{#if model.length}}
  {{view App.MapView}}
{{/if}}
...
```

This will ensure that your `App.MapView` is then rendered when your model has data and therefore you will have also access to the data in the view's `didInsertElement` hook as you'd expect.

#### Update

Your `reRender` hook is named slightly wrong, it should be `rerender`

```
rerender: function() {
  debugger;
}.observes('context.content')
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: So, this seems to work but I think it would cause some performance problems. If you don't render the view until the model loads, you can't load the dom as early as possible, and there would be a reflow when the model gets loaded. Ideally the map would be displayed immediately, and the pins would be shown when the model was loaded. Also, would this work even if the model was loaded but had 0 items from the server? And this did seem to let didInsertElement have a loaded model, but this.get("context.model").toArray()[0].latitude exists, but is undefined (it renders properly for the route)

Comment: Fair enough, you could still stick to your `rerender` approach, the reason it get's never called is because you are naming the hook slightly wrong, instead of `reRender` it should be `rerender` all small cased

Comment: Thanks for your help so far, I'm grateful that you are helping me on this, I've been stuck all day. I don't think changing it to rerender is the fix. I believe that is the name of the hook on views, but that is unrelated to the problem. A better name for that function is probably updatePins (I changed the original post) as I want to redo the pins on the map when the model changes, so I need to observe the model getting changed. Even then, it still isn't triggered on context.content or context.model